# JavaFX TableVie .setCellValueFactory to String without object

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a table which populates a list of objects, in one of the columns I have a `comboBoxColumn`. Although the `combobox` column is not part of the `object` class, I just want it to display a `String` in the column.

How would i do this? Without setting the `object` class.

```
comboBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(new **Just String**);
```

Here is the code

```
@FXML
TableView<Dog> BookDogTableView;

@FXML
TableColumn<Dog, String> BookDogNameCol;

@FXML
TableColumn<Dog, String> BookDogBreedCol;

@FXML
TableColumn<Dog, Integer> BookDogAgeCol;

@FXML
TableColumn<String, String> BookDogSelectRunCol;


BookDogNameCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, String>(
                    "dogName"));

    BookDogBreedCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, String>(
                    "breed"));

    BookDogAgeCol
            .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, Integer>(
                    "age"));

    BookDogSelectDogPane.setCellValueFactory(new **Just String**);

        BookDogSelectRunCol.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(runOptions));

    BookDogTableView.setItems(customersDogs);
```

Comment: You can't do this: it simply doesn't make any sense. If you have a `TableView<Dog>` you can only add `TableColumn<Dog, Something>` to it. The first type in the table column is the type of thing represented by the row, which is `Dog` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I get you right. If you just want to display the same `String` in this column in every row, you would do the following thing:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Dog, String> BookDogSelectRunCol;
...
BookDogSelectRunCol.setCellValueFactory(x -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>("Just String"));
```

This will pass `"Just String"` to the cell. If you just want the `String` to be displayed in the cell, you're done. If you want to display a `ComboBox` as you mentioned and use the String for it in some way, you'll have to use the `setCellFactory` method.

```
BookDogSelectRunCol.setCellFactory(x -> new TableCell<>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            // Your code ...
        }
    });
```

The value of `item` would be `"Just String"` in this example.

But, as James_D already pointed out, the first type parameter passed to a `TableColumn` has to be the same type as passed to the `TableView`.